# Print output of command if output is not null else echo no output

Tags: bash

I am running a command in bash. I would like to run the command only once.

If the command has an output, print the output. But if there is no output, echo out something like `No output`

My command is

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy sap-development  --flatten="bindings[].members" --format='table(bindings.role)' --filter="bindings.members: user:some@email.com"
```

If there is a result, it prints an output. If there is no result, nothing is printed in the output.

I could do something like

```
if [[ $(gcloud projects get-iam-policy <PROJECT>  --flatten="bindings[].members" --format='table(bindings.role)' --filter="bindings.members: user:some@email.com" ) ]] 
then
    gcloud projects get-iam-policy <PROJECT>  --flatten="bindings[].members" --format='table(bindings.role)' --filter="bindings.members: user:some@email.com"
else
    echo "No permissions found"
fi
```

But I find this too redundant. Is there an alternative where I can use the command only once ?

Comment: Does `gcloud projects` have an exit status that corresponds with whether it had output? If so, you don't need to capture or redirect its output at all; `gcloud projects ... || echo "No output"`

Comment: Unfortunately, the exist code in both cases is `0`. So doing the above returns empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if output=$(something); [[ $output ]]; then
  printf '%s\n' "$output"  ## less-buggy alternative to echo "$output"
else
  echo "Nope"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option:

```
gcloud ... | { grep '.*' || echo "No output"; }
```

How it works: the `grep` matches and prints everything it gets over the pipe; if it doesn't find *anything* it exits with a failure status, in which case the `echo` runs.